# If i set length of my char to 80 in mysql, and dont validate for that, would that be exploited

Tags: mysql, char, overflow, string-length

Here is sample code.

```
create table (id int(11) not null, name char(80));
```

and while taking input, i dont validate the maximum length, i just see if the user input value is not null, than insert or update table.

if some user input value more than 80 characters, than Query will not run and will return SQL Error, now is this SQL error Exploitable ??

My First & Last Guess is "No".
Prove me Wrong with Examples.

Thanks & Reqards

Answer (score 4):

You are wrong. **Query will be executed and will return only warning**. first 80 chars will be inserted and the rest ignored! try yourself. open phpmyadmin make this table of yours and then insert 81 character or more to name column, and you will see! http://goo.rs/rK6sWE of this.

Comment: I dont use phpmyAdmin, and in any case, it should not have taken, as mysql donesnot truncate exceeded length. For sake of purpose, i gave try from my mysql CmdLine, and returns an error message ` Data too long for column 'ip1' at row 1`.

Comment: all you have to do is select @@sql_mode :) thanks for comment

Comment: that command is used to show you Server SQL Modes. Examples: SET sql_mode = ‘IGNORE_SPACE,ANSI_QUOTES’;
SET sql_mode = ‘STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO’;

Comment: Well, did you went through the question, or may be i am not able to get your short message answer...

I asked, if user feeds value more than 80 chars.. than can that be used for further exploitation..

For Getting Data written, by default, there is no way that mysql will write rest of the value truncating the overflow value....

Comment: Yes I understood your question and the answer is No. We gave you here real time examples and explanations.

Comment: Eh! I get it, well thanks for sweet reminding of sql_mode, sometimes, i sit like joker and behave like king and ruin everything out... if anything was rude, ignore it, was not with that intention.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you try to put 100 characters of input into a 80-character field, the attacker can't exploit that.  However, you'll get a run-time error, so you should still be making sure your data will fit in the columns before you try to stick it in the database.

Comment: Well, i have just given an else condition on my failure of query, and output "query failed".. 
Now, i don't think its important to make sure data will fit when i can say query failed or some other message and ask him to submit again...

Please prove me wrong Andy is it really important enough to make sure, or can be ignored...

Answer (score 1):

`name char(80)` only ensures that MySQL will refuse to store anything longer than 80 chars. However, before this data even gets written into MySQL (say from your web form), there would be no such guarantee.

If you are really concerned about security, you should always use prepared statements and binding variables.

Comment: By Default it doesnot Store, as per "user [pregmatch](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1108279/pregmatch)" with the `@@sql_mode`, it can, while i am hunting for 'sql_mode' purpose, but this is for sure, mysql cmdline doesnot do it by default.